# Can you add subfolder to layout in Eclipse Android project?

Tags: android, eclipse, layout, resources

When I create a subfolder in the layout folder, and drag an xml file to it, the generated R file doesn't seem to show the subfolder. a) is there a way to change that b) is the file and file structure still picked up by SVN and c) so, if I do it that way, can I still just refer to the object using layout?

Comment: You can't have subfolders, but maybe it's worth considering a library project to hold some things.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can the Android Layout folder contain subfolders?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930398/can-the-android-layout-folder-contain-subfolders)

Answer (score 4):

> When I create a subfolder in the
>   layout folder, and drag an xml file to
>   it, the generated R file doesn't seem
>   to show the subfolder

That is because that is not supported by Android. You cannot have subfolders of resources.

PHP_Jedi's advice, though, is good (e.g., `svn:ignore`).

Comment: that's not that great. If you have lots of layout files, dot dot dot.

Answer (score 3):

Its all automatic.

a )The generated R class only contains static integers for each item in your layout.

b) What is picked up by svn is all up to you, but I usally put the gen folder to svn:ignore

c) if you put the gen folder and the R.java into svn you could get problems since a old version of the file can be checked in/out of the respository. This will happen if you are part of a team. So, put svn:ignore on the gen folder.

Comment: Subfolder in the res folder is generated as internal classes to the R class in the gen folder. Just have a look at the R.java