# How to implement configuration qualfier for multiple screen size in android

Tags: android

I am designing for supporting multiple screen size application using dip like margin_top etc. in 3.2. What are the folders I have to create for the value folder? Where do I have to specify dip? Can anybody tell me how to do this? If I had given value-11 folder and loading layout. I got a compilation error `no resource found error`, but I have layout there.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry you can't do it, check this existing SO Question: [Can the Android Layout folder contain subfolders?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930398/can-the-android-layout-folder-contain-subfolders)?

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways to switch your layouts.  Here are the top two:

Suppose in your code, you are going to inflate `R.layout.my_layout`.

- Switch directly by adding selectors to layouts

Implement layouts:

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml
res/layout-land/my_layout.xml
res/layout-w600dp/my_layout.xml
```

- Switch indirectly by adding selectors to values

Implement layouts:

```
res/layout/my_layout_narrow.xml
res/layout/my_layout_wide.xml
```

Implement values:

```
res/values/layouts.xml
    <resources>
        <item name="my_layout" type="layout">@layout/my_layout_narrow</item>
    </resources>

res/values-land/layouts.xml
    <resources>
        <item name="my_layout" type="layout">@layout/my_layout_wide</item>
    </resources>

res/values-w400dp/layouts.xml
    <resources>
        <item name="my_layout" type="layout">@layout/my_layout_narrow</item>
    </resources>

res/values-w800dp/layouts.xml
    <resources>
        <item name="my_layout" type="layout">@layout/my_layout_wide</item>
    </resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Use dp instead of dip and put the below lines in The Android Manifest.xml file above <application/> tag & put your all images in simply drawable folder .Doing all these changes your app support all screen sizes.`<supports-screens 
          android:smallScreens="true" 
          android:normalScreens="true"
          android:largeScreens="true" 
          android:anyDensity="true"  >
          </supports-screens>
```

Comment: dp and dip should be the same.  I always use dp, though.

Answer (score 0):

See the guide topic [Supporting Multiple Screens > Declaring Tablet Layouts for Android 3.2](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DeclaringTabletLayouts). You can specify resource folders for available width and height or for smallest width. For instance, you might have

- `res/values-sw600dp` in which you would define `margin_top` when the smallest screen dimension available to your app is at least 600dp
- `res/values-w1024dp` in which you would define `margin_top` when the screen width available to the application is at least 1024dp

etc.