# Android layout XML files in a subdirectory not being found

Tags: android, android-layout

I tried to organized my layout.xml files, and made a directory

```
/res/layout/content/
```

Then I tried to point to a file there from the code like this:

```
setContentView(R.layout.content.product_strategy);
```

but I get an error that the content is not a field that can be resolved.

What am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Plz refer to this one: [Can the Android Layout folder contain subfolders?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930398/can-the-android-layout-folder-contain-subfolders)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't make your own resource folder in android.
Please take a look at this link provding information about resource folders:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

Answer (score 2):

R.java doesn't create references to subdirectories in resources. That's the reason. So you need to use the single level default directory structure.