# How to see the Graphical Layout of an XML file in a folder within /res/layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I can see the Graphical Layout of the XML file within the `/res/layout` folder, but not the ones inside my `/res/layout/signup` folder. Does this mean I can only create XML layout files inside `/res/layout`? The other tab when I open the XML files in `/res/layout/signup` is "Structure," not "Graphical Layout." I'm using Eclipse, by the way.

**Update:** I tried moving the files from `/res/layout/signup` to `/res/layout` and now I can see their graphical layouts. So is this really a problem with the folders?

Comment: just right click your xml file and select "open with"==> Android Layout Editor

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930398/can-the-android-layout-folder-contain-subfolders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

unfortunately /res/layout doesn't support child folders.

I'm pretty sure it's because R manages it's references as a `List`, and as such all layouts must be on the same "level".

Try appending what would be the folder as a prefix to the layout name--

signup_editform.xml
signup_tips.xml
...

Comment: Yeah that's what I did. Thanks.