# How can I add a sub folder to the raw folder in my Android app?

Tags: android, android-resources

Of course I can right click the raw folder and add new folder but when I export the project, the APK file does not contain the new sub folder.

Comment: Check out: [Can the Android Layout folder contain subfolders?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930398/can-the-android-layout-folder-contain-subfolders) it discusses the `/raw` folder too.

Answer (score 48):

You can't.

The folders in `/res/` have a predefined structure, and you can't add subfolders.

However, seeing as this is the `raw` folder, you may want to look into using the `assets` folder, in which sub folders are supported.

Keep in mind thought that by using `assets` you won't be able to use `R.*.*` references anymore. You will have to go through the [AssetManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html).