# Android Studio Error: Input file needs to be a normal file

Tags: android

While making an app (specifically, Udacity->Android Basics->Multiscreen Apps 
 ->Lesson 5->7.Challenge), I copied a bunch of mp3 folders directly to a raw folder in the res directory. I get the error while building the project. The top line is "Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'." Couldn't find the cause on Google. Can someone explain to me the error and how to fix it?

Comment: Yes. Actually, I just copied all the contents of a folder to the res, assuming it had only mp3 files. Didn't know it had a subfolder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The raw folder must not have subfolders. So all your mp3 files need to be inside res/raw.

See this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15508178/5956451