# How can I avoiding having a flat drawable directory in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, assets, android-drawable, organization

I understand that Android Studio does not support subdirectories as specified in [Can the Android drawable directory contain subdirectories?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1078988/10950986).

My question is, what is the standard way to handle this problem when working with a lot of assets? My general workflow would benefit greatly if I was able to see similar assets in one directory separate from other assets.

An example:
Instead of having

```
drawable 
- a_asset_01
- a_asset_02
- a_asset_03
- b_asset_01
- b_asset_02
- b_asset_03
```

Maybe I can have somethinging "similar" to

```
drawable
- a_assets 
-- a_asset_01
-- a_asset_02
-- a_asset_03
- b_assets
-- b_asset_01
-- b_asset_02
-- b_asset_03
```

Again, I understand that this cannot be done in Android Studio, I'm simply looking for the next best thing.

Comment: Its stupid but you can just use the different drawable quality folders to break them apart assuming you won't use them for quality differences and just use one copy. Android will grab the only file available where ever it is in drawable. Otherwise, I guess you're stuck with needing a good naming scheme.

Comment: Alternatively, you can maybe use assets with sub folders (this is supposedly possible) but then you have to code everything in which might be a bigger pain ^_^ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15508160/how-can-i-add-a-sub-folder-to-the-raw-folder-in-my-android-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify new source-sets! You can have separate folders wherever you want, for example you can have `~/my_assets/A/assets`, `~/my_assets/B/assets` and `~/my_assets/C/assets`. All you need to do is tell Gradle where to find them by adding them to the `assets` source sets in your `build.gradle` file:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    sourceSets {
        main {
            assets.srcDirs += ['/full/path/to/my_assets/A/assets/', 'full/path/to/my_assets/B/assets/', 'full/path/to/my_assets/C/assets']
        }
    }
}
```