# In Android Studio, can layout xml files be grouped into folders?

Tags: android, xml, layout

In Android Studio, can layout xml files be grouped into folders?

Able to do it with the java files by creating different packages/folders, can the layout files be similarly grouped/organized?

Looking for ease of organization in my workflow when i have a ton of xml files to work with.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930398/can-the-android-layout-folder-contain-subfolders

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the files have to be in predefined folders.

Here is a link to more information on available folder names:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

Answer (score 2):

Actually, **they can!**

Although the steps are a bit too many, it is indeed possible to group your xml files in folders. Just follow the following steps:

1. Switch to Project view; you can now see all your project folders and sub-folders properly.
2. Backup **all** your layout files; at this stage you'll find them all under android/app/src/main/res/layout.
3. Delete the entire layout directory (android/app/src/main/res/layout). **Remember to properly backup all your layout files before this step.**
4. Right click the res directory and select "New" and then select "Directory".
5. Give it a name; remember the name must be entirely lowercase. Your new directory will now appear under the res folder. Let's call this directory **layouts** for instance.
6. Right click your new directory (layouts) and select "New" and then select "Directory". This way, we are creating a new sub-directory. We can give it any name we want, just remmber it must be completely lowercase.
7. You can repeat step 6 as many times as you want and keep creating sub-directories.
8. **VERY IMPORTANT!** Right click any of the sub-directories and select "New" and then select "Directory". YOU MUST NAME THIS DIRECTORY `layout`.
9. Repeat this for all sub-directories.
10. Move all the backed-up xml files (in step 2) to the `layout` directory  of the folder you want to put them in.
11. Add the code below to your build.gradle (app) file:

    sourceSets {

    ```
    main {

       res.srcDirs =
         [
           'src/main/res/layouts/layout_for_fragment',
           'src/main/res/layouts',
           'src/main/res'
         ]
        }
     }
    ```

Replace layouts with your sub-directory name and add as many sub-directories as are available.

12. Sync project with gradle files

And that's it.. Pretty herculean but it can come in handy anytime. You may want to visit [this link](https://medium.com/mindorks/how-to-put-android-layout-files-in-subfolders-1f7cf07ff48f) for more clarification.

I hope this helps.. Merry coding!

Comment: yes it works, but you forgot to mention `sourceSets ` should go inside `android` tags. I was looking around for like 15 mins coz I put it outside :). but project navigator still put all xmls under a same layout virtual group even thought those xmls are on different folders. is there a way to change that too?