# Why android res structure cannot have subfolders?

Tags: android

It is fairly easy to find information on the web that android res hierarchy cannot have subfolders, and that it needs to be flat. However it is not so easy to find as to why. I'm interested in the answer to the question:

Why res folders cannot have subfolders (when developing with Eclipse IDE, as I know it can be kinda hacked around using Gradle with Android Studio)?

Comment: There is a way to do it. Here is a link about that.

http://stackoverflow.com/a/22426467/618419

Comment: Thanks Emre for the hint. The problem is that this gradle plugin for Eclipse is mentioned as not being officialy supported by google, in the way that they do not recommend using it in relation with android or guarantee it will keep working correctly. So the only reliable way I know of using gradle is with android studio, which I do not wish to use at the moment.