# Xamarin - android: no resource found

Tags: android, xamarin, android-resources

Executing project, a no resource found error appea in file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:oneshot="false">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/spinner/load0.png" android:duration="100" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/spinner/load1.png" android:duration="100" />

</animation-list>
```

My drawable png images are on folder Resource->drawable->spinner->load0, load1.
Where is y fault?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot add folders in the Drawable folder, Since the ResourceDesigner takes care of all this and Android does not allow user-specific folders in the Resource Folder, Try moving them out of the Spinner folder directly in the resources and use them. For more details check these

[Can the Android drawable directory contain subdirectories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077357/can-the-android-drawable-directory-contain-subdirectories)

[Possible to create subfolders in drawable folder in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25805041/possible-to-create-subfolders-in-drawable-folder-in-android-studio)

The folders that are allowed by Android can be found here
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources