# Secondary resources folder in android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

In Android Studio I am trying to get a hierarchy file structure by declaring in build.gradle file.

```
   sourceSets{  
   main   {  
      res.srcDirs =      [  
         'src/main/res/mainfragment',
         'src/main/res'
      ]
   }
}
```

This does compile like it should.
However in the project explorer it doesn't reflect this change.
As in everything is flat. 
I have read [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22426467) that this is not normal behavior.
Is this a bug?

edit:
 on request here a pictures
[image: This is how I want it to look]
The above is how i want it to look

[image: This is how it looks currently]
This is how it looks currently
[image: This is how my folder structure looks like currenlty]
This is how my folder structure looks like currently.

Comment: Could you perhaps provide an image of your project explorer?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: @Squonk I dont want 100 images all under draw-able folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can't quite do what you want. You can have multiple resource folders, but each folder has to have the standard Android resource directory structure. You can't define your own hierarchies inside the res folder.

Comment: I have a secondary android resource structure inside the folder compleet with things like drawable-hdpi

Comment: Yes, there's a standard Android folder hierarchy to organize the resources by type and by other categories, but you can't impose your own non-Android structure on the resources.

Comment: it was possible in prev version. question is this by design or a bug