# Multiple resource folders

Tags: android-studio

I'm trying to add one more resource folder in my Android project.
I created a new folder *extra-res* so my project structure looks like this:

```
  + src
    + main
      + res
        + layout
        + ...etc...
      + extra-res
        + layout
```

So I added this to *build.gradle*:

```
android {
   .........

   sourceSets {
        main {
            res.srcDirs = ['res', 'extra-res']
        }
    }

}
```

But after editing the *build.gradle* file the build fails.

> :app:processDebugResources
> C:\Users\vovasoft\AndroidStudioProjects\sdbm\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml
>
> Error:(13, 23) No resource found that matches the given name (at
> 'icon' with value '@drawable/ic_launcher').
>
> Error:(14, 24) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'label' with value '@string/app_name').
>
> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run
> command:
> aapt.exe package -f --no-crunch -I android.jar -M  \AndroidStudioProjects\sdbm\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml -S  \AndroidStudioProjects\sdbm\app\build\intermediates\res\debug
> -A  \AndroidStudioProjects\sdbm\app\build\intermediates\assets\debug
> -m -J  C:\Users\vovasoft\AndroidStudioProjects\sdbm\app\build\generated\source\r\debug -F (at 'label' with value '@string/activity_edit_field').

Before editing build.gradle the build was successful.

Comment: Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930398/can-the-android-layout-folder-contain-subfolders#answer-22426467

Answer (score 10):

I gave you some wrong information when I answered your original question in https://stackoverflow.com/a/28176489/2985303. That'll teach me about not testing an answer before posting it. You need to more fully qualify the resource directory paths, like so:

```
android {
    sourceSets {
        main {
            res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res', 'src/main/extra-res']
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. Your answer was a good solution but as @Joel mentioned I used this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930398/can-the-android-layout-folder-contain-subfolders#answer-22426467 approach. It is easier to organize my layout resources that way.

Comment: You can also use the += operator. Example: `res.srcDirs += '../../Config/res/'`

Answer (score 0):

I was getting that error beacause I forgot to include my new resource folder in build.gradle file.