# Is it possible to move strings.xml's path/file location?

Tags: android, android-resources

I was wondering if anyone has seen if it is possible to get string resources from another directory. So by default my strings are in something like:

`/MyProject/src/main/res/values` and translated languages in `/MyProject/src/main/res/values-es` etc...

I would like to get my string resources from another file or sub-directory like:

`/MyProject/sub-module/src/res/values` but also have it get values for translated languages the same: `/MyProject/sub-module/src/res/values-es`

I have looked around in the developer documents and other resources but have seen nothing about changing the directory of the strings resources.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The gradle tools let you move the entire `res/` folder with everything in it, but not only the string resources. It's [now possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930398/can-the-android-layout-folder-contain-subfolders) to use sub-folders, so you if you're on Mac or Linux could probably make something work using symlinks.

Moving the entire `res/` folder in gradle:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
            srcDir 'sub-module/src/res'
        }
    }
}
```

The symlinks approach (I haven't tried this, but it might work):

```
project/
  src/
    main/
      java/
      res/
        values/
          dimens.xml
          strings/       <--- actually a symlink to another folder
            strings.xml
        values-en/
          strings/       <--- actually a symlink to another folder
            strings.xml
```

Comment: Awesome thank you for this. I am surprised I could not find anything on this. The symlink approach sounds interesting is there anyway I could make it scalable through git? Or would I have to write some sort of setup.sh to run and add the symlinks?

Comment: I haven't tried that ever, but it seems Git can handle symlinks reasonably well: http://stackoverflow.com/a/954575/49489