# Android - Localization by Country only

Tags: android, localization

Can you localize Android assets based only on country, not language? What I am seeing online tells me it's not possible but it doesn't seem like a good answer. I know you can do like /res/layout-language OR /res/layout-language-rcountry. I would like a layout folder based on just country, regardless of language...

The reason I want this is that in my app, US English has one layout for a particular screen, and a totally different layout for Canada for the same screen. Canada has English and French, so I could duplicate the layout files into /res/layout-fr-rCA and /res/layout-en-rCA but that doesn't seem like a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can always make sub folders under the layout folder and use accordingly in the gradle build system. Refer to this answer to make subfolers:
[Can the Android Layout folder contain subfolders?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930398/can-the-android-layout-folder-contain-subfolders)