# Android: structuring of layout files (e.g. like in subfolders)

Tags: android, android-layout

Is there a way to structure layout files, e.g. like in subfolders (as subfolders of resources are not supported)?

I have many layout files which all lie in the layout folder.
This gets pretty

is it possible to somehow structure them, by tags, by subfolders or something else?

E.G.:

- layout

  - screen A
  - screen B

or

- layout

  - fragments
  - activities

or

- layout

  - component A
  - component B

Comment: whats your requirement

Comment: no, but there is a possibility using gradle, answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930398/can-the-android-layout-folder-contain-subfolders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can have multiple resource folders in your project using Gradle.

It allows you to organize not only your layout files but any kind of `resources`.

This is how the configuration looks like:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res', 'src/main/res2']
    }
}
```

[Documentation](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/resource-merging)

[Example Project](https://github.com/eskimoapps/ResourceNestingExample.)