# Organizing include XML layout files

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I have dozens of XML layouts that are used solely for the purpose of including them within other layouts.

I've tried creating a folder called `includes` under the `layout` directory, but that apparently doesn't work.

How then should I organize my include layouts? Where should I put them all?

Comment: the accepted answer to this question might help .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930398/can-the-android-layout-folder-contain-subfolders .. its possible to use gradle to merge multiple layout folders together.

Comment: Are there other ways to organize include layouts?

Answer (score 3):

Sadly Android doesn't recognize itself different layouts folders.
But with gradle you can configure several folders for your layouts (or other xmls)

Add the folders in your app gradle

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res', 'src/main/res2']
    }
}
```