# Unexpected file added when creating new blank activity in android studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

I got the new android studio, and I noticed one thing when creating a new blank activity.

[image]

**The layout that corresponds with the java for the activity is made twice, once as a `content`:**

[image]

This new layout is an exact replica of the regular `activity_menu.xml` except this one is called `content_menu.xml`. I also noticed this piece of code in the layout code of `activity_menu.xml`:

```
    <include layout="@layout/content_menu" />
```

What is the point of this extra layout? Can I delete it? I found [this](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html) on the official documentation, but I still don't understand why it is necessary. This wasn't there in the first update...

Comment: Is that a folder for `activity_main.xml`? I thought sub-folders in the layout folder were bad

Comment: @cricket_007 I just put those in to be optimal layout for all screens...Was I not supposed to

Comment: Only if you do it correctly - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930398/can-the-android-layout-folder-contain-subfolders

Answer (score 1):

Here `content_menu` is just a name for your `xml` layout content. Don't get confused by this. As you see in your Menu Activity you'll see `setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu)`

Here the activity is told that its layout is the content inside `activity_menu.xml` but in this(`activity_menu.xml`) file you see an include tag. the include tag means that the content inside another `xml` file named `content_menu.xml` must be included inside the current layout at the place where include tag is used. so if want to change the internal content you can leave everything in `activity_menu.xml` as it is and make your changes in `content_menu.xml` and it'll all be visible in your design.

and if you don't want the `content_menu.xml` file you can just copy everything from this file to `activity_menu.xml` in place of `<include > tag` and delete the `content_menu.xml` file.

Comment: Ohhh, that makes more sense. What is the point of this anyway? I will mark you best answer once I get it!

Comment: there are many reasons
1. to seperate the common design part such as 'Toolbar' or 'FAB(Floating action button)' etc from the your main content.
2. to make the code reusable if multiple activity has same content or similar layout, this reason is the most important one.
3. To increase the robustness and readability of code.

Comment: Alright, and in number two you mention reusability. How can we reuse the layout, and why not just use a fragment? Also, is it okay to remove the `content`?

Comment: No, a 'fragment' is a class with its own full fledged life-cycle which uses system resources same as an 'activity' and does the job of dynamic inclusion of ui component, so it has its own purpose, whereas here 'content.xml' is just a static xml file which could be added anywhere statically and won't necessarily be modified at the runtime. 

And yes you can remove the content file if you want to just place your ui code into the 'activity_yourfilename.xml'.

Answer (score 0):

Say for example you want to reuse `content_menu.xml` content somewhere else, in that case in other activity you will do the same include statement in xml file. The point is that you are reusing the same xml and reducing number of content.

Comment: Why not just inflate menu again?

Comment: @RuchirBaronia - You wouldn't inflate `content_menu`. Say you include `content_menu` within `activity_menu.xml` and `fragment_menu.xml`. You would inflate the later instead.

Comment: ...I am really lost right now. What is the point of the `content` and why do we need to reuse it? Is the reason for performance or something? I have no idea what `content` even is, let alone how to inflate it...Thanks

Comment: @RuchirBaronia - basically you *can* delete `content` as long as you replace the `include` line in the XML of `activity` with the full contents of `content`

Comment: @RuchirBaronia - The purpose of having `content` at all and `include`-ing it, is so it can be reused elsewhere in other menus. Say you had a "Quit App" menu item in `content`, you could then `include` that menu item in all your other menus without retyping it in all the other ones.

Comment: Isn't that just a fragment...?