# Adding elements to the layout?

Tags: android, performance, android-activity, layout, android-studio

I had [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34079156/what-is-with-this-layout) question earlier today, and have been stuck on this for 3 hours!

The answer suggested that it is okay to remove the `activity_content` as long as I remove the line:

```
    <include layout="@layout/content_menu" />
```

I did that...And started to edit directly in the layout, after copying the **default** contents of `content`, except...**the layout isn't even there when editing!** So, am I supposed to keep both layouts, and just edit the content one? Why do I even need to do that? Is there a reason for this update in android studio?

I'm just creating my activities like this:

[image]

Comment: Please post your activity_menu.xml

Comment: @BenjaminScharbau I copied the **default** code from `content` and pasted it into `activity_menu`

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't get your problem. You copied the code from `content` into `activity_menu`, but your app is not displaying it as expected, right?

Comment: @BenjaminScharbau Yes, and the relative layout isn't showing in the component tree either. Can you explain what `content` even is?

Comment: `content` is included if you want to use your layout in different fragments so you can reuse it.

Comment: And for your question: You must have deleted your `activity_menu` somewhere on accident.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can just leave the activity_yourclassname.xml as it is and make changes to content_yourclassname.xml only for the main content.

and yes this update is made just to make code more cleaner and more reusable. so that you could focus only on the main internal content of the code without getting into complex layouts.