# Android: Organize layout folder

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gradle-plugin

How could I organize my `layout` folder in `Android Studio`? I want to add `subfolders` to it.

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930398/can-the-android-layout-folder-contain-subfolders) question but nothing happens when I modify my `gradle` file. As I see a lot of up votes I think it works, but I can't figure out how and why it doesn't work for me. I cleaned project, restart Android Studio, invalidate caches but still nothing.

Comment: have you tried out https://github.com/dmytrodanylyk/folding-plugin

Comment: @GeorgeThomas It looks like a good idea but: ``Make sure your are in Project structure view, NOT Android.`` I want to simplify my work, not to see more folders and subfolders in Project structure.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's so strange It doesn't work. Let me show you how I build my Gradle (the part where you set dependencies):

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.app.yourapp"
    minSdkVersion 22
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

    sourceSets {
        main {
            res.srcDirs =
                    [
                            'src/main/res/layouts/activities',
                            'src/main/res/layouts/fragments',
                            'src/main/res/layouts/content',
                            'src/main/res/layouts',
                            'src/main/res'
                    ]
        }
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}


dependencies {....
```

and that's It.

Hope I've been helpful.

Comment: If I have debug flavor, do I have to rewrite the same content for that?

Comment: This is once and for all