# Manage layout sudirectories

Tags: android, android-studio, layout

My layout dirctory starts to be messy. As the java directory, can I create subdirestories for layout? I creates Res subdirectory in studio 1.5. I can see them in the directory, but not through the studio.

I've read [Can the Android Layout folder contain subfolders?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930398/can-the-android-layout-folder-contain-subfolders?rq=1) specially the very good comments from hitch.united but I was wondering if that is still valid with studio 1.5?

why can't I see my created dir through the studio?

Comment: The solution you referring to is still valid and still the only way of solving it. And, what's even worse, in Android Studio 2.0 it's still not supported out-of-the-box.

Comment: Thanks. I hope the studio guys are monitoring the list. Maybe they are looking into improving this.

Comment: yep, we just can keep our fingers crossed. :-) That's seems to be pretty obvious thing to improve in the IDE.. Converted comment into the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution you referring to is still valid and still the only way of solving it. And, what's even worse, in Android Studio 2.0 it's still not supported out-of-the-box.