# sub folder for layout in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, layout, directory, subdirectory

I developing an android project for my university. My layout folder is too big, and i decide to create sub folder in my layout folder.

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930398/can-the-android-layout-folder-contain-subfolders?rq=1) answer and question but this is not work for me.

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "example.google.com.widgetforlockscreen"
    minSdkVersion 8
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        res.srcDirs =
                [
                        'src/main/res/layouts/layouts_category2',
                        'src/main/res/layouts',
                        'src/main/res'


                ]
    }
}
}
```

but nothing create for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gradle won't create any directories for you. You have to create the following directory structure,

```
- res/layouts
    - layout
        - layout1.xml
    - layouts_category2
        - layout
            - layout2.xml
```

Like this, we can use Gradle's ability to merge multiple resource folders. Note that it's not an Android feature.

Comment: thank you very much Msp.I understood my Problem with your answer.God bless you