# Creating layout subfolder for different screen sizes

Tags: android, resources, subdirectory, screen-size

I want to create subfolders in layout-sw320dp and layout-sw480dp but I recieve duplicate resource error.
How I can create sub layout folders while keeping layout-sw480dp and layout-sw320dp system.[image]

The question is not duplicate. In this section I am using sw320dp sw480dp so I can create better layouts for different size devices. In the suggested one there isnt anything supporting that. There is only one type of device size information.

I am saying I want to keep this screen size identifying layouts but inside those I want to create subfolders.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can the Android Layout folder contain subfolders?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930398/can-the-android-layout-folder-contain-subfolders)

Comment: No I am talking about the screen width folders also. like layout-sw480dp, layout-sw320dp, layout-sw600dp

Comment: @NJ did I get myself clear ? Or should I write more what I am trying to explain ?

Comment: @NJ Because of you flagging my question as duplicate which is not, no one is seeing in the system.

Comment: Have reversed my vote :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that after you have done your subcategories under that you can actually do layout-sw320dp, layout-sw480dp etc. This question was not duplicate and it was unique.