# How to create subfolder with supporting different screen sizes?

Tags: android, layout, resources, subdirectory

First of all I know how to create subfolder when I have only one Layout. That is not the issue. The issue is that I cannot create subfolders under
layout-sw320dp
layout-sw480dp
layout-sw600dp
layout-sw720dp

Because the layout file names are same in these folders it gives duplicate resource names.
I want to create subfolder in these so How can I do it?

NOTE: Some "Smart" people things this is a typical subfolder question but it is not. So dont mark this question as duplicate question.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can the Android Layout folder contain subfolders?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930398/can-the-android-layout-folder-contain-subfolders)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that after you have done your subcategories under that you can actually do layout-sw320dp, layout-sw480dp etc.
This question was not duplicate and it was unique.

Answer (score 0):

**Why did you create sub-folder in layout?**

simply create folder according to screen size and place layout which vary according to screen size say,a layout name activity_main.xml

place it in

**-layout:activity_main.xml
-layout-sw320pd:activity_main.xml ...  ....  .. so on**

If it say duplicate resource ignore that warning because Android itself supporting switching of layouts.

Comment: I will have lots of files in sw320dp I need to have subfolders inside that so I can organize them properly.

Comment: it is an error also not a warning so you cannot ignore that