# Can I make different subfolders in layout using Android Studio?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

According to past answers, the answer was no, but there were hacky workarounds.

Nowadays is it permitted to make subfolders under the Layout folder so I can organize my xml files a bit better?

Comment: https://plus.google.com/+DmytroDanylyk/posts/bjYgPZFK1ti

Comment: Those past questions have other answers that tell you how to do it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can the Android Layout folder contain subfolders?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930398/can-the-android-layout-folder-contain-subfolders)