# How to create my own directory in android studio?

Tags: java, android, directory

Friends. I want know is there any way to create a directory in android studio.And the call that directory in MainActivity like.

```
R.layout.my layout;
```

insted of that I want

```
R.(my directory).mylayout;
```

Comment: I believe this is something you are looking for (pretty informative answer there): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930398/can-the-android-layout-folder-contain-subfolders

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it. For instance if you want to read a csv file in your project. Then make a folder in the res folder of your project (let's name this folder raw). Then place a file in the folder. So the folder structure will be something like this res->raw->evolver.csv.

Now to read this file, you can do something like this to read this file.

```
InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.evolver);
```

Here "evolver" is the name of the file that I placed in the folder res->raw.

Answer (score 0):

- Right Click on your layout folder and create new folder name it whatever you want.
- Add whatever file you want to access in your folder.
- To Access your file type `R.layout.(your Directory).`

this should do it

Comment: Pretty sure it doesn't work that way. You have a source?