# uri is not registered http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I am getting uri is not registered on my code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"/>

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview01"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </WebView> 
</LinearLayout>
```

I have created a dir **tabdir** under the **main/res/layout.** and want to create xml file in tabdir.

Answer (score 2):

If you create a sub directory, android studio will not recognize it as a standard resource directory.  You can see the effect by changing project explorer mode from 'Project' to 'Android' in Android Studio.

[image]

[image]

Well, if you need to create a subdirectory, follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930398/can-the-android-layout-folder-contain-subfolders) SO thread.
Or a quickfix to your error is to move your layout file to the  main/res/layout directory.

Answer (score 1):

New layout folders have to be added to `sourceSet`, otherwise the schemas won't be recognized. Here how to do it for `gradle` guys:

**project grade file**

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        //add folders following order from leafs to root. 
        res.srcDirs = [
                'src/main/res/layouts/layout_controls/layout_new_control',
                'src/main/res/layouts/layout_controls',
                'src/main/res/layouts/layout_main',
                'src/main/res']
    }
```

Each folder declared must have at least a sub folder named `layout`.

Other sub folders may be added to hold different type of resources for the new source the same way there are sub folders to `res` folder, e.g. `values` sub folder can be added to hold strings translations in a strings.xml file.

The content of layout_new_control folder would be something like:

```
-- layout
     new_control.xml
-- values
     strings.xml
```

**The errors will only disappear after compile.**

For more check this [guide](https://medium.com/mindorks/how-to-put-android-layout-files-in-subfolders-1f7cf07ff48f).

Comment: Do you mean `res.srcDirs` or `resources.srcDirs`? The former gives me an error.