# Android Studio URI is not registered after grouping layouts into subdirectory

Tags: android

I tried grouping the layout for my Android project into several subdirectories. I was following this answer.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32194963/688954

But somewhat the IDE complains `URI is not registered` and the Gradle build also says `Error:Error: Unsupported type 'android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout'`.

Can anyone help?

I'm using build tools version 24.0.1

[image]

Answer (score 0):

sourceSets must be under android

```
android {
   ....
   sourceSets {
      main {
          ...
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have used any underscore '_' in new resource directory name (**/res/layouts-all/layout** is proper, but **/res/layouts_all/layout** is wrong), please remove it. Do clean build.
Then this error will be removed.
I could solve my problem by this.

Answer (score 0):

Your xml file must be in the folder which is named "layout"

[image]