# Android organizing layout resourse?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to organizing layout resource.

Following:
 - res/layouts 
 - res/layouts/activities 
 - res/layouts/fragments
 - res/layouts/other

But my gradle is only creating "activities" directory.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.khash.viewpagerexample"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main{
            res.srcDirs = [
                    'src/main/res/layouts/activities',
                    'src/main/res/layouts',
                    'src/main/res/layouts/fragments',
                    'src/main/res/layouts',
                    'src/main/res'
            ]
        }
    }
    }

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-alpha1'
}
```

How i can add all(activities, fragment , other, main) directory to res.

Comment: 'src/main/res' , 'src/main/res/layouts','src/main/res/layouts/activities',
                    'src/main/res/layouts/fragments',
             have you tried it in this order ?\

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22426467/8089770 try this answer. hope it helps

Comment: yeah i tried it by order

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

**Try this :**

1. Change android -> Project
2. Rename layout -> layouts
3. Create new directory inside layouts named it as activities and fragments.(this folder names is sync with gradle. **use same name as used in gradle.**)
4. Create layout directory in each directory you have created in layouts.
5. Put your xmls as you want in your directory.

**Gradle file:    build.gradle(app)**

```
sourceSets {
            main {
                res.srcDirs =
                        [
                                'src/main/res/layouts/activities',
                                'src/main/res/layouts/fragments',
                                'src/main/res/layouts',
                                'src/main/res'
                        ]
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is your solution okay with after    1. rebuild -> 2. clean -> 3. File - > Invalidate caches / Restart ?

Comment: soory i can't get you

Comment: 1. Build -> Rebuild 2. Build -> Clean 3. File -> Invalidate caches/ restart

Comment: this process after is your solution okay?

Comment: from android i can't see difference. But it works perfect for project.

Comment: yes because android only find layout directory and merge in that so

Answer (score 2):

Best Practice :
Create prefix like as follows

- Activity Layout name start with activity_
- Fragment Layout name start with fragment_
- Adapter Layout row name start with list_
- Dialog Layout name start with dialog_
- Other Layout  start with content_

  After then Install Android Studio Plugin ( Android File Grouping )

[image]