# Creating sub folders within 'layout' res folder

Tags: android, layout, android-gradle-plugin

I have created sub directory 'caching' within the res-layout directory and when I placed an XML file within caching it complains 'URI is not registered'.

I looked up online and some say it is not recommended to create sub directories withing layout and some suggest to add the following code in the build.gradle.

app: build.gradle

```
sourceSets {
        main {
            res.srcDirs =
                    [
                            'src/main/res/layouts/caching',
                            'src/main/res/layouts',
                            'src/main/res'
                    ]
        }
    }
```

My Structure

```
--res
   --layout
      --caching
          cache_save_layout.xml
```

Where the error occurs -- "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" - URI is not registered

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</LinearLayout>
```

Could you suggest what is the right way to fix this.

Thanks in advance
R

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44581013/android-organizing-layout-resourse/44582145#44582145

Comment: The simplest solution is to get rid of the `caching` directory and put `cache_save_layout` in `res/layout/`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android organizing layout resourse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44581013/android-organizing-layout-resourse)

Comment: @CommonsWare thank you for your response but that was not what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> try follow

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        res.srcDirs =
                [
                        'src/main/res/layouts/activity',
                        'src/main/res/layouts/fragment',                          
                        'src/main/res'
                ]
    }
}
```

> Your structure should like this:

```
--res 
    --layouts
        --activity
           --layout
              --main_activity.xml
        --fragment
           --layout
              --main_fragment.xml
```

Comment: Please don't use quote-formatting for any and all text you write. It is meant for quotes thus the name....