# Android studio src/res/layout subfolder error

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, subdirectory

[StackOverflow Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36931232/7105963)

I read that article and tried to **make subfolders** in app/src/main/res/layout/

I think I did the whole things which are mentioned in that answer.

### In my gradle:

```
apply plugin: 
apply plugin: 
apply plugin:
apply plugin: 

android {
    // something
    sourceSets {
    main {
        res.srcDirs = getLayoutList("app/src/main/res/layout/")
    }
}
def getLayoutList(path) {
File file = new File(path)
def throwAway = file.path.split("/")[0]
def newPath = file.path.substring(throwAway.length() + 1)
def array = file.list().collect {
    "${newPath}/${it}"
}
def res="src/main/res";
array.push(res);
return array
}

dependencies { ... }
```

### My directory hierarchy model (Project)

```
Test
-- .gradle
-- .idea
-- app
  -- build
  -- libs
  -- src
    -- androidTest
    -- main
      -- assets
      -- java
      -- res
        -- layout
          -- about_login
          -- timetable
          -- activity_main.xml
      -- AndroidManifest.xml
    -- test
-- build
-- gradle
-- .gitignore
-- ... // Lot more setting files
```

But when I sync my gradle, the error came up and said, **index error**

> def newPath = file.path.substring(throwAway.length() + 1)

at that line. Please help me.

### Why this is different question?

1st. Many people works in their own PC but, I can't
2nd. I think that there has relationship between String.substring()
3rd. I cannot solve this problem.

Comment: So, I was trying to change `throwAway.length() + 1` to `throwAway.length()` but, then, error appears. cannot find `R.id.~~` (But, in java, there is no compile error)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can the Android Layout folder contain subfolders?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930398/can-the-android-layout-folder-contain-subfolders)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a simple mistake in your project structure. you need to create a **layouts** directory **NOT** *layout*. So it should be:

```
app/src/main/res/layouts/
```

Then in your subfolder, you need create to create a **layout** directory. This should be where your layout file reside. For example, if you have `login_activity.xml` which you want to create inside subfolder **about_login**, you need to create the following directory:

```
app/src/main/res/layouts/about_login/layout
```

So, the `login_activity.xml` path will be:

```
app/src/main/res/layouts/about_login/layout/login_activity.xml
```

Then, in your **app** **build.gradle**, you should add the following:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
      res.srcDirs =
          [
              'src/main/res', // Try removing this
              'src/main/res/layouts',
              'src/main/res/layouts/about_login',
          ]
    }
}
```

Each time you need to create a subfolder, you also need to create **layout** directory and add the XML layout file inside the layout directory.

Then your directory hierarcy should be like this:

```
Test
-- .gradle
-- .idea
-- app
  -- build
  -- libs
  -- src
    -- androidTest
    -- main
      -- assets
      -- java
      -- res
        -- layouts
          -- about_login
            -- layout
              -- login_activity.xml
          -- activity_main.xml
      -- AndroidManifest.xml
    -- test
-- build
-- gradle
```

You can commenting your following code below, because we didn't need it:

```
def getLayoutList(path) {
File file = new File(path)
def throwAway = file.path.split("/")[0]
def newPath = file.path.substring(throwAway.length() + 1)
def array = file.list().collect {
    "${newPath}/${it}"
}
def res="src/main/res";
array.push(res);
return array
}
```

Comment: Sorry for late comment and upvote. But, I have more question. Is that possible that subfolder in subfolder? Like `src/main/res/layouts/about_login/fragment_id_password/layout` ??

Comment: Yes, it possible. My current project is using 3 subfolders from layouts. But I haven't try beyond those 3.

Comment: Thank you!! I will figure out the problem of that codes written groovy :(

Comment: You're very welcome. Try commenting it first, I don't have any groovy code for setting the directory layout hierarchy, only the `sourceSets` part.