# Sorting xml files in a directory

Tags: android, layout

I have lots of xml files in my layout folder and I am trying to sort them in directories according to their categories.

Here's the result I want:

[image: xml files sorted in a folder]

creating a directory does not display it in the project, how can I go about this?

Comment: I tried that also. Traditionally, you can only separate them by name, you cannot organise your resources into your own folders. If ou really want to, take a look [here](https://antonioleiva.com/android-multiple-resource-folders/). It's a good place to start.

Comment: this might helps, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930398/can-the-android-layout-folder-contain-subfolders