# How to include subfolder layout with <include/> tag android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, xml-parsing

I already search the article and search question on this forum both only showing "how to setting gradle sub directory"

I already set the `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ardyfeb.kolabs"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
          res.srcDirs = [
               'src/main/res/layout/partials',
               'src/main/res/layout',
               'src/main/res'
          ]
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

My directory tree

```
src/main/res
      -- layout
           -  main.xml
           -- partials
               - header.xml
```

My question is :
How to include the `partials/header.xml` ? With  tag

Example :

```
<include
        layout="@layout/toolbar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/header"/>
```

Comment: What's the issue? Are you not able to import that?

Comment: include
  layout="@layout/header"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:id="@+id/header"/>

Comment: The error show "no resouce found"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22426467/6891563

Comment: See if you have build project, and follow these answers.

Comment: How to include that xml file on <include/> tag, the article show answer for "how to include xml on java"

Comment: Can you show me example?

Comment: Do you have multiple `header.xml`? And you want particular `partials/header.xml` ?

Comment: In layout/main.xml i want to include layout/partials/header.xml

Comment: Inclue with <include/> tag

Comment: file > sync project with gradle files (try this)

Comment: Thanks for all answer :) i hope god bless you. I finally to use butterknife for alternative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<include
        android:id="@+id/tagOne"
        layout="@layout/header"
        ...
        />
```

and

```
<include
        android:id="@+id/tagTwo"
        layout="@layout/header"
        ...
        />
```

**Example**

If you have `TextView` then you can find views by tag like

```
TextView headerOneText = findViewById(R.id.tagOne).findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

And

```
TextView headerTwoText = findViewById(R.id.tagTwo).findViewById(R.id.textView);
```