# How to structure the folder R.layout?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-resources

I'm developping my Android application but I'm not right with the project structure because I have all my layout in the folder *R.layout*

Isn't any way to structure this folder like packages. One folder for activity an other for content, fragment, etc..

Comment: see this link may help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930398/can-the-android-layout-folder-contain-subfolders

Comment: Maybe this will help https://medium.com/mindorks/how-to-put-android-layout-files-in-subfolders-1f7cf07ff48f

Comment: Thanks Very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a bad practice, avoid doing that. Always try to follow [official guides](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources) now it might not seem clear and logical why? and what?, but in a long term you are going to understand and be happy that you followed official guides and best practices.

Happy coding!

Comment: I have not finish my app but i have yet 13 layouts, I doesn't know if it is a good pratice to have too many layouts. As for me, it's not but I'm not expert.

Comment: It might be even a hundreds. For good management of them just use good naming conventions  so search would be easy

Answer (score 0):

You can add folder as your package name and declare in manifeast file the path of your folder.
And it is good pratice because it directly id