# Android studio layout sorting by subfolders not working

Tags: android

I have managed to move my `layout` files into separate folders using [this link](https://medium.com/mindorks/how-to-put-android-layout-files-in-subfolders-1f7cf07ff48f). I moved the `.xml` files according to the folders, added the `gradle` `sourceSets` and after I `Sync`, on the `Android` view of the project on the `res` folder, it still appears the `layout` folder, showing me all the `.xml` files alltogheter. Somehow this view gets all the subfolders `layout` and still shows them togheter. Is there any way to make subfolders so in `Android` view to show subfolders? I want to manage the files better, not to have them all.
This picture shows how the folders are listed, even though they are separated.
[image]

Comment: You should check this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930398/can-the-android-layout-folder-contain-subfolders

Comment: That's where i got my link from. Well, my bad that I havent read the rest of answers. They say it s not possible

Comment: Yes, it's possible, You can check the link, works so good