# Is this the correct way of writing sourceSets for multiple folders of the same type?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I used to have all my files in one folder of each type but recently I found an option do it in multiple (at least I think so) - orig. question [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930398/can-the-android-layout-folder-contain-subfolders)

I tried to do it the way they did in the answer but there was a note on [android site](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants) that you should avoid specifying a directory which is a parent to one. And so I did the following:

[image]

The code doesnt fail grandle sync but I am not sure if it works because even if I change the name of "mipmap" to something that isnt in the res folder it will sync anyways..

**Is this the correct way of writing sourceSets for multiple folders of the same type?**

1. Should I add the srcDirs add to each directory in res folder meaning font/layout/menu/raw/values
2. Is this the correct way of setting a source directory for mipmap which has multiple qualifiers?

Thanks for any help

**EDIT** : @MEETPrajapati This error popped in one of the drawable files once I synced it. [image: error]

Comment: if you have many product flavors then you should consider this. Otherwise, why make things so complicated?

Comment: @MEETPrajapati my original 'Drawable' folder has more than 100 files now and it was getting a little hard to find the right file in it. Think this option might make it more clear

Answer (score 0):

You can make a new drawable folder inside new res folder called "module1" like this :

```
    sourceSets{
    main {
        java.srcDir("src/main/java")
        res.setSrcDirs(["src/main/res","src/other/module1"])
        manifest.srcFile("src/main/AndroidManifest.xml")
    }
}
```