How to create sub directory in res>layout folder in android studio?
I am using kotlin and kotlin DSL
I want to create sub directory under layout directory. So that I can manage my layouts
more effieciently.
There are many layout files, so it is such a mess to manage them.
I tried it many ways, but failed.
Like whenever I create directory under layout folder . It doesn't show in android view, but shows in project view. Fine, then when I create any layout file inside that sub directory, it goes to inside layout directory directly.
If there any similar ways to manage layouts, please tell me.
Here is an image of what I want to do actually .
This image is collected from a medium post.But that post was too old, so It doesn't work now
I apologize for my poor language.

I don't know if the thing you are showing in image is possible or not but, if you are having so many layout files, that means your project is growing and you should think about doing modularization it. that way you will have the layout files of specific module only under layouts dir.

I think you followed this https://proandroiddev.com/split-layout-into-subfolder-in-android-5bf76f805e90 tutorial but, it is very old and things might have changed since then.

have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/q/4930398/14102903 SO question to see if any of it's answers work for you.

What you are seeking is not directly supported by the Android development tools. I agree with the first comment: your solution should be breaking your app into multiple modules. It will address your concern, and it is the supported approach for addressing your concern.
