# Can I put layout directory's xml file in different subdirectories in Android?

Tags: android, layout

I want to know can I put res/layout directory's all xml files in subdirectories of res/layout directory.
For eg res/layout/settings_layout,res/layout/menu_layout etc.

Comment: Duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930398/can-the-android-layout-folder-contain-subfolders and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547100/can-you-add-subfolder-to-layout-in-eclipse-android-project

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you do this, the entries will not get added to your R class and so they won't be available to you.

Wouldn't it have been much more simple to just try it than to post the question and wait for an answer?

Answer (score 3):

Android does not support nested folders under the layout in res. Its only a linear structure.

In otherwords, , Android eclipse does not support having subfolders of resources.