# Can android layout files be put in to different folders or groups

Tags: android, eclipse

There is already a similar question , but I am not satisfied with the answer

[Can I put layout directory's xml file in different subdirectories in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6505373/can-i-put-layout-directorys-xml-file-in-different-subdirectories-in-android)

because there are too many xml files , if they are not into different group ,I can not find the specific one that I want .
Do you guys have any different method to solve this problem such as virtual group or something ?

Answer (score 0):

As you can read in the linked question, and in the questions linked to this question, it is not supported to have custom folders inside the folders supported by Android.

You could clean up your files by following naming conventions, like `layout_xyz.xml`, `image_abc.png`, ...

Answer (score 0):

I use the namespaceing technique, 
i.e.
addnewrecord_main.xml
addnewrecord_custombutton.xml
addnewrecord_newbutton.png

search_listviewitem.xml
search_bgimage.png
etc